# How to concatenate Perl variables with a hyphen?

Tags: string, perl, string-concatenation

I am trying to concatenate two or three variables with hyphens. Please check the below example.

```
my $QueueName   = Support;
my $CustomerID  = abc;
my $UserCountry = India;
my $Count       = 12345;

my $Tn = $QueueName.$CustomerID.$UserCountry.$Count;
```

I am getting the following output:

```
"$Tn" = SupportabcIndia12345
```

But I want it like this:

```
$Tn = Support-abc-India-12345
```

Comment: Side-note: you should have `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of every Perl script you write. This will require you to quote your strings, e.g. `my $QueueName = 'Support';`, but it will help you avoid a lot of common errors, like typos in variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't good Perl, and wouldn't run under `use strict`, which you really should be using.  If you were, you'd see errors displayed.

Write it like this, instead:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $QueueName   = 'Support';
my $CustomerID  = 'abc';
my $UserCountry = 'India';
my $Count       = '12345';

my $Tn = "$QueueName-$CustomerID-$UserCountry-$Count";
print "$Tn\n";
```

You have to quote strings. If you want a hyphen you can use the method above to allocate the values separated by a hyphen.

Comment: Actually it is valid to concatenate two variables without putting them in quotes: `my $var = $string1.$string2` is perfectly valid Perl syntax.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 Dr.Avalanche is referring to the use of barewords, e.g. `my $QueueName   = Support;`, which won't work under strict subs. The OP probably doesn't know about strict, so that should really be explained better.

Comment: Oh, then yes, Dr. Avalanche is correct.  If `strict`/`warnings` is in use that will result in an error . . . and you should ALWAYS use `strict`/`warnings`.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`join()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) to join list elements with delimiter,

```
my $Tn = join "-", $QueueName, $CustomerID, $UserCountry, $Count;
```

Answer (score 5):

You should be using `strict` and `warnings` to enforce good programming habits. While your solution is technically valid Perl it would fail the `strict` test since you are trying to define variables with "barewords".

---

To fix this, put these two lines at the top of your code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Then modify your code to fit the rules of the `strict` module.

ex:

`my $QueueName = Support;`

should be:

`my $QueueName = 'Support';`

---

As for concatenating the variables this will work:

`my $Tn = $QueueName.'-'.$CustomerID.'-'.$UserCountry.'-'.$Count;`

-or-

`my $Tn = "$QueueName-$CustomerID-$UserCountry-$Count";`

The `join` function will also work:

`my $Tn = join '-', $QueueName, $CustomerID, $UserCountry, $Count;`

---

Depending on who will be maintaining your code, the first two methods may be more readable to those who are inexperienced with Perl.

Comment: as complete as you wanted to be, you neglected to give a nice example of how to use the join() operator. please add that to the answer

Comment: I didn't include it because that was already covered by another answer.

Comment: An example of `join` has been added.